# Specific instance plagiarism of work found on Stack Exchange site where I cannot flag

Tags: discussion, support, plagiarism

Around a year ago [I posted on the Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/573559). The post contained text pictures and some Mathematica code.

This morning a colleague alerted me to the fact that the entire contents of this post had appeared on the Mathematica Stack Exchange site. The [post itself is identical except for the title; the text, code and even the pictures are exactly the same](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130566/crack-it-if-you-can-but-in-the-best-way). Effectively the post has been plagiarised and put on Stack Exchange.

I posted on the Stack Exchange question with a link back to the original question, I then commented on this to say that the two were exactly the same. My post was subsequently deleted.

I've looked at some of your FAQs and I'm told to raise a flag to a moderator if I think plagiarism has occurred, but I think I cannot do this as a new user.

I'm not sure what to do here. My feeling is that either the post ought to be deleted, or at the very least there ought to be a link to the original question, posted by myself on a different forum more than a year ago.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't have access to flagging, you can contact the Stack Exchange team directly. In the footer of every page is a "contact us" link.

[image: MSE footer with "contact us" link circled]

That leads to a web form: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact, allowing you to send off a message that will be read and handled by an employee. They'll get back to you via email as soon as reasonably possible.